# Colored fully bars in bar vertical plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

I created a plot with pgfplots using this snippet of code:

```
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{semilogxaxis}[ybar stacked,ymajorgrids=true]
            \addplot [red]
                table [x=nodes,y=1]
                {./MATLAB/grafici/energia/broadcast_scenario/energy_broadcast_varpktslossprobability_100nodes.txt};
        \end{semilogxaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

I got as result the correct plot, but the bars aren't fully colored. Only the borders of this bar are colored of red, instead I would like them fully colored also internally.

Comment: Ok problem solved...It exists the command fill

Comment: It would be great if you could post an answer to your question and self-accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fill a stacked bar it needs to add the command `fill` to `\addplot` and eventually `draw` to color the outside borders